# DB initializer does not work with CreateDatabaseIfNotExists works will all other types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

As the title says for some reason my database is not being created when specifying CreateDatabaseIfNotExists works fine with drop always and drop if model changes. The database is not created I get an error when in my view because the data is empty.

DBContext

```
public class SchemaDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public SchemaDBContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new SchemaDBInitializer());
        }

        public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SalesStaff> SalesStaffs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CreditCard> CreditCards { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enquiry> Enquiries { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TripImage> TripImages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Coach> Coaches { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

        public DbSet<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShoppingCart> ShoppingCarts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

Initializer

```
public class SchemaDBInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SchemaDBContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SchemaDBContext context)
        {
            var customers = generateCustomers();
            customers.ForEach(s => s.ShoppingCart = new ShoppingCart());      
            customers.ForEach(s => context.Customers.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var salesStaffs = generateSalesStaffs();
            salesStaffs.ForEach(s => context.SalesStaffs.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var customerUsers = customers.Select(u => u.User).ToList();
            var salesStaffUsers = salesStaffs.Select(u => u.User).ToList();

            var userRoles = new List<UserRole>
            {
                new UserRole()
                {
                    Role = "Customer",
                    Users = customerUsers
                },
                new UserRole()
                {
                    Role = "SalesStaff",
                    Users = salesStaffUsers
                }
            };

            userRoles.ForEach(s => context.UserRoles.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var trips = generateTrips();
            trips.ForEach(s => context.Trips.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var tickets = generateTickets(customers, trips);
            tickets.ForEach(s => context.Tickets.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var reviews = generateReviews(customers, trips);
            reviews.ForEach(s => context.Reviews.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var enquiries = generatEnquiries(customers, salesStaffs);
            enquiries.ForEach(s => context.Enquiries.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var orders = generateOrders(customers);
            orders.ForEach(order => context.Orders.Add(order));
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
}
```

The seed method is not being called by initializer.

Comment: Off-topic, but I think it's better to have one `context.SaveChanges();` call in the Seed method (save all or nothing). On-topic: I assume you tested this while the database actually doesn't exist. But I'd expect you to see exceptions popping up when EF tries to create it?

Comment: @GertArnold I tested it while the database didn't exist. I don't get an exception with creating/initializing the database the exception shows up when view tries to use data from the database. The .mdx is not being created.

Comment: @GertArnold it seems like seed is not being called so maybe it thinks that there is a database somewhere even though I deleted the mdx file.

Comment: @GertArnold it's built in sql express database. I believe something might have went wrong with migrations? Since I manually deleted mdx file maybe I'm supposed to delete something else before it believe that the database does not exist.

Comment: So you probably mean mdf file.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes I meant mdf file